# Adding functionality to a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
from p in IPACS_Procedures
where !(from pd in IPACS_ProcedureDocs
       join d in IPACS_Documents on pd.DocumentID equals d.DocumentID
       where d.DateDeleted == null && d.DateApproved != null
       select pd.ProcedureID).Contains(p.ProcedureID)
select new { p.ProcedureID, p.Name }
```

The above works but we have a version control system in place.  I need to add in the ability to check if there is a version with a higher version that is not yet approved.

The above code looks for any `document (d)` that is not marked as Deleted `(DateDelete)` and it has been approved `(DateApproved)`.

I need to add in the ability to check the Versions table to see if there is an unapproved version and if it has been marked as deleted or not.

After many attempts I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
d.IPACS_Versions.Where(v => v.revision > d.revision && v.dateDeleted == null)
```

Specifics:

```
d.DateDeleted must equal null to be valid
d.DateApproved must not be null to be valid

d will always have a record in IPACS_Versions but if the record in IPACS_Version 
has a higher revision than d.revision and if the higher version then dateDeleted 
must be null to be valid in the above list.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) instead of `Where`:

```
from p in IPACS_Procedures
where !(from pd in IPACS_ProcedureDocs
       join d in IPACS_Documents on pd.DocumentID equals d.DocumentID
       where d.DateDeleted == null && d.DateApproved != null &&
             d.IPACS_Versions.Any(v => v.revision > d.revision && v.dateDeleted == null)
       select pd.ProcedureID).Contains(p.ProcedureID)
select new { p.ProcedureID, p.Name }
```

Comment: This doesn't pull the desired results it's pulling almost every single document.  Without the .Any it pulls 172.  With any it pulls 369 which is just about every single document we have which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I wrapped the first line by the where in () changed that ending && to || then wrapped the second line of the where in () and it is pulling 150 documents which is about where I need it, just need to verify if it is pulling the right documents.

Comment: @JamesWilson I think the `!(...).Contains(p.ProcedureID)` is throwing me off. The inner query should meet the specifications you asked for but then you're sort of inverting the results. Can you clarify what you want the final result set to contain?

Comment: I didn't write it and the person who did write it isn't here for another week.  But basically a procedure can have a document attached. We have a drop down list.  We limit a procedure to only being able to have a single policy or procedure attached to it.  This code removes a procedure from the list if it has one attached.  I just need to update it so if there is a pending approval it is also removed.